# Convert [Days, hh:mm:ss] to [hh:mm:ss]

Tags: excel, time

Some data i export to Excel appears like this: '3 Days, 2:15:37' (when the period exceeds 24 hours only, [hh:mm:ss] otherwise, which is ok).
How can i display it on Excel as [hh:mm:ss] even when it exceeds 24 hours?

Comment: What is your desired output for `3 Days, 2:15:37`. Also, are you planning to perform any calculations using this column? hh:mm:ss is a time format, so displaying 72:15:37 is not a valid time value.

Comment: The desired output would be ```74:15:37```... The idea is to display a duration expressed in hours. Does that answer the question? I think the file will be read into R at a later stage to perform other calculations indeed...

Comment: Thanks for specifying this is not a valid time format. If that is the case, then what would be the best way to handle this considering that we plan to re-use this volume of hours to perform further calculations?

Comment: When you don't have "days", how is something like 04:22:34 represented? Is it 04:22:34 or 4:22:34? Guess the same question when Days is present too. I would first recommend trying to adjust where these data are coming from. But if transforming in Excel is your only option, then it's easier if your HH are HH, not H (such as 04 is easier than 4).

Comment: ```4:22:34```- when i open the file, it appears with a 'General' format

Comment: I did change the SQL code from the query extracting the information and generating the data exported to the excel file. Actually, I used extract ```epoch / 3600``` and that returns a total of hours with fraction of hours. Let's see what the feedback will be... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you'll find a better method, but here's one method that involves using some helper columns. Since your column is of General format, then it's going to recognize some of your cells as Time except for those with "Days". You have a mixture of formats so it's a but cumbersome.

You can probably consolidate a couple steps here, but breaking it out better identifies a process. Column A is your original data.

Column B: Formula to extract data to the right of "comma space":

```
=IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,10),A2)
```

Column C: For cells containing the word "Day", take the value to the left of it and multiply by 24.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("Day",A2)-1)*24,0)
```

Column D: Extract the HOURS from your time format of column B.

```
=HOUR(B2)
```

Column E: Take the MM:SS from column B.

```
=TEXT(B2,"mm:ss")
```

Column F: Put it all together:

```
=CONCAT(C2+D2,":",E2)
```

[image]

Here's one way to combine the last two steps, which would reduce the number of helper columns by one.

```
=CONCAT(C2+D2,":",TEXT(B2,"mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Thank you. As i mentioned above, i eventually resorted to changing the source SQL query code. But if that does not do, we'll keep it in Excel and use your different steps above. Thanks for taking the time...